# Is there a way to put nested classes in a separate file?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5, partial-classes

I have a Java class that is about 4,000 lines long (lots of methods). This class then uses about 200 small classes that only it needs, so another 4,000 lines of code.

If this was C# I would put those other in a partial class file (different file), but they would remain private nested classes only visible to the parent class.

Is there a way to do this in Java? I'm not asking for some methods to be in a distinct file, but for private nested classes to be in a distinct file.

Comment: I did a search and could not find this here, although I'm guessing it's been asked before.

Comment: No, there's not partial classes in Java. Although you can use some sort of aggregation to achieve similar benefits/functionality.

Comment: Any reason not to just have them as classes in the same package? (By the way, a class file that's 4000 lines long, is about 3800 lines TOO LONG)

Comment: Are the classes static, or do they use some of the "lots of methods" in a 4000-line class?

Comment: Put this class and all of the child classes in a separate package, then give the child classes package-private visibility.

Comment: By "child" classes, you mean nested classes, right? I would suggest editing the question to indicate that, as otherwise "child" sounds like "subclass". But no, you can't write nested classes in a different source file.

Comment: @Stewart: I don't think it's a good idea to put arbitrary limits on the lengths of classes. Without context, we really can't know whether that's too much or not. You'll find plenty of types that are about a thousand lines long in https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/tree/master/src/NodaTime, but I generally don't feel they're too large. If you've got a fair number of methods, each of which has significant amounts of documentation, it can easily mount up.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - it's a ton of static classes, most of them under 10 lines of code.

Comment: @Stewart - This is code that parses a very complex XML file turning it into an internal object. We have a nested class for every node type to process that node. And we have a ton of utility methods so we don't have duplicate code across all those nested classes. This would be a complex mess if we tried to reduce the main handler down to a bunch of 200 line classes. As to the second file, yes it's a ton of distinct classes but all in one file so we don't have 200 source files (also a mess).

Comment: @AndyTurner - I don't think the package-private gives me anything. The default visibility is a bit more restrictive than that and it works fine. The separate folder might help, need to think that through. Thanks.

Comment: @David default visibility *is* package private. What do you mean?

Comment: @AndyTurner - sorry, right. I bounce between JavaScript, C# and Java so much I get them conflated at times

Comment: @DavidThielen  If you have a ton of utility methods, sounds like at least they should go in a class of their own.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a class private to only another class while putting it in a different file.

### Use no class access modifier

What you can do is put the classes in separate files with no access modifiers (omit "public"), which will make them package-private, i.e. visible only within its own package. See also [the official Access Control tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

UtilClasses.java:

```
package OurPackage;

class UtilClass1
{
}
class UtilClass2
{
}
```

MainClass.java:

```
package OurPackage;

public class MainClass
{
   UtilClass1 iAmAUtilClass;
}
```

---

### Use interfaces or inheritance

You can also achieve something similar with either interfaces or inheritance, by omitting the access modifier from the nested class. This would also be package-private, but this might be preferable to the above in some circumstances, since it avoids having all the nested classes at the top level.

BaseInterface.java:

```
package OurPackage;

interface BaseInterface
{
   class UtilClass1
   {
   }
}
```

MainClass.java:

```
package OurPackage;

public class MainClass implements BaseInterface
{
   UtilClass1 iAmAUtilClass;
}
```

You can also use a base class instead of an interface and extend that with roughly the same effect.

You don't need to implement `BaseInterface` gain access to its nested classes, but, if you don't, you'd need to use `BaseClass.UtilClass1` instead of just `UtilClass1`.

Answer (score 1):

Inner private classes can't be "extracted" and still be visible only to one particular class. One solution is already mentioned in the comments: Create a package that contains the "main" class and all the previously inner classes and make the inner classes package visible. This would also allow you to create unit tests testing for the correct functionalities of the inner classes, which is something that is most likely currently not happening simply because the inner classes can't be "reached" by a unit test at the moment.

Concepts like declaring "friendships" between classes like in C++ don't exist in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the inner classes with top-level ones, but you'll have to rewrite a lot of things by hand that the compiler auto-wires for you with the inner-class relationship. To the Virtual Machine, an inner class is nothing special, it's just another class in the same package as the outer class with a fancy name. But the compiler creates a lot of helper constructs under the hood, that you have to reconstruct by hand (or have some refactoring tool do that for you):

- The inner class can refer to the outer `this` instance, by prefixing it with the outer class name. You need to pass the outer `this` into your inner constructor and store it in a field like `outerThis` to get access.
- In the source code, you can call the outer-class methods directly. You need to rewrite it like `outerThis.method()`. The same applies to fields.
- For private outer methods and fields to become accessible, the compiler creates bridge constructs for you. You have to either change access modifiers or create package-private bridge methods yourself.

In the end, you'll have the former inner classes at least package-visible and being more verbose than the original ones, but on the other hand you'll get better isolation and testability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using JUnit 5 (in Kotlin, but with a little change  should be fine for Java too).

MyContainerTest.kt (or .java) file:

```kotlin
class MyContainerTest {
    @Nested inner class MyNestedTestsOne : MyNestedTest1()

    @Nested inner class MyNestedTestsTwo : MyNestedTest2()

    // Can also have regular unit tests
    @Test
    fun myUnitTestInContainer() { /* ... */ }

    @Test
    fun myOtherUnitTestInContainer() { /* ... */ }
}
```

MyNestedTest1.kt (or .java) file:

```kotlin
abstract class MyNestedTest1 {
    @Test
    fun myUnitTestInNestedClass1() { /* ... */ }
}
```

MyNestedTest2.kt (or .java) file:

```kotlin
abstract class MyNestedTest2 {
    @Test
    fun myUnitTestInNestedClass2() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Nested test classes have been extracted to separate files and then in the desired container class, placeholder nested classes have been created which inherit from those. This way, they are shown as the sub-hierarchy of the container test class in test views and reports.

Note: Make those nested classes abstract to avoid running them twice.

See https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1750